# Can anyone help me explain this Loedal diagram scenario? (Special Relativity)

Tags: special-relativity

I'm just confused as to what it says in the diagram. Could somebody please explain?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the diagram is showing why FTL communication can lead to causal paradoxes. Apparently O and A, and A and B, are spacelike separated, and there are arrows leading from O to A and from A to B. From this, and the text in the diagram, it seems to be describing something like a [tachyonic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone) wherein an observer "at rest" sends an FTL message to a remote party who is "moving", and who then uses the same kind of mechanism to send the message back in time to the original observer. This is because all velocities, including FTL ones, are relative, and a message that is at 100x the speed of light in one frame may actually be traveling backwards in time in another frame. The wikipedia article has more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a spacetime diagram that shows two objects moving at constant velocity along the x'' axis from the frame of reference of an observer. There should be vertical t'' and horizontal x'' axes for the frame of reference. We would normally use x or x', but those names have been taken. We will have to imagine these axes.

The blue ct' line shows the position of one object as a function of time. You can see that as t'' gets bigger, x'' gets bigger. The observer sees the object moving toward +x''.

The horizontal x'' axis is a snapshot of the entire 1D space at t'' = 0. Every point in the space is shown at that instant.

Likewise, the x' axis is a snapshot of the entire 1D space at t' = 0, taken by the blue object. The object has a different notion of what is simultaneous than the observer.

You can see that if two lights flashed at (x'',t'') = (0,0) and (1,0), observer would say they happened at the same time. If he is sitting at (0,0), he would see one flash immediately, and the other when the light arrived.

The blue object passes O at t'=0. At that instant, one flash occurs. But he says the other flash occurred in the past. You can see that by drawing lines parallel to x' and t' through the event where the second flash occurred. The second flash is not on the snapshot of all space for t' = 0.

And similar for the black object.

Comment: and could you also explain the words in the figure? I'm having a hard time trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to see in the diagram, but the blue line connecting A to B does not lie in the X,X' plane and in fact goes backwards in time. To B the information from A arrived before O sent the information to A. Later On B arrives at O's location in space in and time and then asks O to send the information to A who will send the information to B in the past.

Take a look at my answer to the [Alcubierre Drive thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197130/how-does-a-world-line-of-an-alcubierre-drive-look-like/799157#799157) that deals in more detail with faster than light travel and the consequences of being able to send signals backwards in time.