What happens to "time" inside a "warp field"
I know this is a silly science fiction question, but it does serve a purpose.
If a "warp drive" (much like Star Trek) could be built. If it was essentially used to travel faster than light, would those within the field experience time passing slower? So from their point of view, would it still take the same amount of time to reach their destination as traveling in a mundane fashion, even though from the perspective of outside observers the vessel would be travelling faster than light?
I am currently fleshing out the premise for a science fiction short story, and I want the science "true"

Since there is no such thing as a "warp drive" or faster than light travel, the science in your story will never be "true". The good news is that it's your story so you can make things in it behave just as you like.

@gandalf61 Nah Spacetime warp drives have been theorised, however they are VERY hypothetical devices which is somewhere between physics and science fiction.However based on the physics we know , we can assume how such a device would work.If everybody thought the since it doesnt exist , there is no point in thinking about it then we wouldnt have had ANY inventions and this is very anti-scientific , invention is part of science.

This is a excellent video from Misio Kacu.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUBwtkCg8Gc

It would be much clearer I think to replace "time" with "clock" in GR, because time has spiritual connotations, while clock (biological/mechanical) is just the rate that something ticks.

This question is probably better suited for WorldBuilding.SE

@RootGroves The issue isn't that a warp drive hasn't been built and is therefore unscientific. The issue is that even the proposed warp drive metrics like the Alcubierre metric come with fundamental problems and no one knows whether they can be resolved or not. For example, you need matter with exotic properties and we don't know if this exists, an observer may not be able to survive inside of one, and quantum gravity effects may prevent them from working via the chronology protection conjecture. You can write papers about them but it's a huge stretch to say we know how they would work.

Hypothetical warp systems like the Star Trek warp drive and the Alcubierre drive that claim faster than light travel, have ridiculous outcomes like allowing the vessel to return to where it came from, at a time before it left. Why not just have something slightly more feasible like a drive that allows something like 0.99999999999999c which would allow travel over many light years in a matter of minutes of proper time? Not fast enough for you?

See my answer on the problems with FTL drives in a related question:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/798221/388464

There is actually a way to analyze the behavior of light and the like in Alcubierre spacetime; I can pull up some of my old work on the subject.

@RootGroves Please try to avoid sloppy errors Iike "Misio Kacu".

Thanks for the answers, apologies to admins if I breached a rule. I have enough to work with I think.

No warp drive has ever been constructed; the Alcubierre drive was estimated to require an amount of energy equal to around five billion times the total mass-energy of the observable Universe times negative one, which aside from impossible to obtain is negative and violates quantum things. That doesn’t mean we can’t think about time dilation in Alcubierre spacetime.
Time dilation has its origins in the spacetime metric. For flat spacetime, the metric is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d}x^2-\mathrm{d}y^2-\mathrm{d}z^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d}\sigma^2$$
and from this you clearly see that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\equiv\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
if you let $\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma}{\mathrm{d}t}=v$. The Alcubierre metric, on the other hand, is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2= c^2\mathrm{d} t^2-(\mathrm{d} x-v_s(t)f(r_s)\mathrm{d} t)^2-\mathrm{d} y^2-\mathrm{d} z^2$$
which after some calculation gives an alternative form of the Lorentz factor
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}(-f^2(r_s)+2f(r_s)-1)}}$$
for motion restricted to the $x$-axis. Inside the warp bubble, $f(r_s)\approx 1$, and you can easily see that the Lorentz factor goes to approximately $\gamma\approx1$ for all $v$. Ordinarily, kinematic time dilation goes up to infinity at $v\to c$, but in Alcubierre spacetime within the warp bubble, the Lorentz factor (which of course measures time dilation) stays at unity for all values of velocity. This is why the A-drive works: you can also see that light rays (where $\mathrm{d}s=0$) travelling in the $x$-direction get to infinite speed inside the warp bubble, which might be problematic, but also that there isn’t time dilation within the warp bubble at all, which not only is convenient for the observer within the warp bubble but also means that arbitrarily-high velocities can be attained.
In other words, the captain of the Enterprise and the onlooker on Earth see the ship take the same amount of time to reach the destination, even if it’s moving at a hundred million times $c$.

Kinetic time dilation requires movement through spacetime (or through the gravitational field as Einstein would describe).  It seems that a warp drive moves the rocket and the spacetime bubble surrounding it.  So the rocket and people on board are stationary inside their spacetime bubble.  So no, they would not experience kinetic time dilation.
An anaolgy would be that you are floating in a hot tub on board a ship.  While the ship is moving through the ocean water, you are stationary in the water of the hot tub.

There are also warp drives that are equivalent in energy requirement and effect that don’t use expansion, but are more complicated. See Natario et. al.

It can take less proper time to travel with a conventional drive.
Consider a warp drive traveling at 5c from Earth to a destination 5 light years away. It will take 1 year of Earth time to travel and the passengers will age by one year (and it will feel like one year) because the warp drive means they do not benefit from relativistic time dilation.
A conventional rocket travelling at 0.999985c will take just over 5 years of Earth time to travel to the same destination, but to the passengers it will feel like ten days and they will only age by ten days. The trip will take about 3% of the proper time it takes to travel by warp drive, from the passengers point of view. However the warp drive rocket will arrive at the destination nearly a full year ahead of the conventional rocket.
That is the simplistic view. The warp drive passengers do not feel the g forces of acceleration, but the conventional rocket passengers do. This means the conventional rocket is limited to accelerating with a constant proper acceleration of one or two g. This reduces the average velocity of the conventional rocket and the proper time saving are not so clear cut. Factor in that the conventional rocket has to start slowing down at the half way point in order to be able to come to a stop at the destination and things get a bit worse for the conventional rocket. The calculations are little involved, but some example calculations are done in this excellent web article on the relativistic rocket.
One example is that a conventional rocket accelerating continuously at one Earth g and slowing down at the half way point, would take over 30,000 light years of Earth time to travel to the centre of the galaxy, but the passengers would only age by 20 years. The warp drive travelling at 5c would take 6,000 light years of Earth time to travel the same distance, but the passengers would age by 6,000 years (So not one generation of passengers.) If you are travelling to a distant destination and want to arrive at the destination, before you die of old age, it is probably best to take the fast conventional rocket.
In order for the warp drive passengers to age no more than the passengers on the conventional rocket, the warp drive would have to be capable of 183c.
However, travelling at relativistic speeds has its own special hazards and challenges. Any space debris becomes a dangerous projectile and significant shielding would be required. Some background radiation can be Doppler shifted to dangerous X rays and Gamma rays and special shielding will be required to protect the passengers from the amplified radiation.

One point for Trekkies;  Warp 5 is 125  times the speed of light   https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119942/why-is-warp-5-so-special-or-is-it

@foolishmuse Point taken. Changed all speed references to multiples of c instead of Star Trek warp factors.
